# Can Autofac compose existing objects with Mef dependencies?

Tags: mef, autofac

I am integrating a mef-based ServiceLocator with Autofac. The current locator is able to compose an **existing** object by setting up a CompositionBatch and then injecting dependecies on the object. A simple repro:

```cs
public void MefCompositionContainer_CanComposeExistingObjects()
{
    //1. Initialize Mef
    var composablePartCatalogs = new List<ComposablePartCatalog>
    {
        new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        //A lot more here..
    };

    var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(composablePartCatalogs);
    var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog, true);
    //2. Mef is able to compose existing object
    var objectWithPropertyImport = new ClassWithPropertyImport();
    Compose(container, objectWithPropertyImport);
    objectWithPropertyImport.ImportOfMefExport.Should().NotBeNull();
}

static T Compose<T>(CompositionContainer container, T value)
{
    var batch = new CompositionBatch();
    batch.AddPart(value);
    container.Compose(batch);
    return value;
}
```

The following classes are required:

```cs
[Export]
public class MefExport { }

//Note that this class does not have the [Export] attribute
public class ClassWithPropertyImport
{
    [Import]
    public MefExport ImportOfMefExport { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish the same with Autofac? If so - what should be added / changed here to compose objectWithPropertyImport?

```cs
public void Autofac_CanComposeExistingObjects()
{
    //1. Initialize Mef
    var composablePartCatalogs = new List<ComposablePartCatalog>
    {
        new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        //A lot more here..
    };

    var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(composablePartCatalogs);

    //2. Initialize Autofac and setup mef-integration
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Register(c => new AutofacExport()).Exported(x => x.As<AutofacExport>());
    builder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(aggregateCatalog);

    var ioc = builder.Build();

    var objectWithPropertyImport = new ClassWithPropertyImport();
    // Now what?

    // Updated according to solution from Travis Illig.
    // The following code works for me:
    ioc.InjectProperties(objectWithPropertyImport);
    objectWithPropertyImport.ImportOfMefExport.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is inject the properties of a new object using Autofac, then use the `InjectProperties` method on the lifetime scope / container.

```
using Autofac;

public class ClassWithPropertyImport
{
    public MyExport ImportedProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyExport { }

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyExport>();
var container = builder.Build();

using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var c = new ClassWithPropertyImport();
    scope.InjectProperties(c);
    c.ImportedProperty.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

As long as the types you're injecting are registered with Autofac, it should work fine. You don't need the type of the thing you're injecting onto registered. (Note the `ClassWithPropertyImport` is not registered with Autofac but the `MyExport` class is.)

Keep in mind it does mean Autofac needs to resolve the `MyExport` type - so if it has dependencies, those do need to be registered with Autofac as well.